# What more can i do to this infinite sum?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, alternative-proof, hypergeometric-function

This question sprung out from another post of mine that was in part by Semiclassical, he Proved the Following:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {}_2F_1(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-n}{2};\frac{3}{2};1)/n! = 2\pi [I_0(1)+L_0(1)]
$$
Then i came up with a solution of my own that is:

$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {}_2F_1(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1-n}{2};\frac{3}{2};1)/n! = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}( \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{a=0}^{\infty} [\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1-n}{2}+a)}{ a!(2a+1) \Gamma(\frac{1-n}{2})}])
$

Therefore my questions isn't really to prove that the statements are equal, but just to prove that:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}( \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{a=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(\frac{1-n}{2}+a)}{ a!(2a+1) \Gamma(\frac{1-n}{2})}) = 2\pi [ I_0(1) + L_0(1)]
$$

Without converting the series back into a hyper-geometric function if possible, or perhaps shed some light on the matter because i couldn't simplify the series anymore with the identities i know about gamma functions to explicitly connect the two (in my eyes). Also i have used Mathmatica to check that the expression is true.

Comment: Recall how in the other posts, the answers started by using Gauss's identity to equate the hypergeometric term to a quotient of gamma functions. So your question here could be boiled down to showing that the series representation of $2f1$ converges to that quotient. (which is how Gauss proved the identity in the first place!)

Comment: @DavidH I don't follow, all i did was change the rising factorials in the power series representation of the hyper-geometric function to its gamma function identity, then i simplified using gamma function identities. I feel like this can't be as far as i can bring it down, i know i can use other identities to further manipulate the expression but i cannot see how it will help further. I'm sorry Perhaps i am misinterpreting what you are saying all together?